# How many ideals with fixed norm value

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm doing some number theory exercises with solutions. Well, I can't understand the solution to one of them.... the exercise asks for how many ideals $A$ in $R$ we have $N(A)=2^2\cdot 11^3$, where $R$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-6}]$. We have $2R=\mathfrak{p}^2$ and $11R=\mathfrak{q}_1\mathfrak{q}_2$, for suitable distinct prime ideals $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}_1,\mathfrak{q}_2$. Let $A=\mathfrak{p}^a\mathfrak{q}_1^b\mathfrak{q}_2^c\mathfrak{r}$ be the factorization of $A$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ (eventually equal to $0$) and $\mathfrak{r}$ coprime with $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q}_1\mathfrak{q}_2$ (eventually equal to $R$).

This is the first point I don't understand: why do I need to suppose the presence of such an $\mathfrak{r}$? I mean, $2R=\mathfrak{p}^2$, $11R=\mathfrak{q}_1\mathfrak{q}_2$, $N(A)$ divides $2^2 11^3 R=\mathfrak{p}^4\mathfrak{q}_1^3\mathfrak{q}_2^3$, so why there is $\mathfrak{r}$?

Then
$$2^2\cdot 11^3=N(A)=N(\mathfrak{p}^a\mathfrak{q}_1^b\mathfrak{q}_2^c\mathfrak{r})=2^{2a}11^{b+c}N(\mathfrak{r})$$
implies $a=1, b+c=3$ and $\mathfrak{r}=R$, hence there are only four ideals....

Now, is there a typo? Why do $N(\mathfrak{p})=2^2$? Isn't it $=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting these from? You are correct, unless I am also making a mistake.

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime with $\mathfrak{p}\mid A$, then $\|\mathfrak{p}\|\mid \|A\|$. But, $\|\mathfrak{p}\|=p^{f(\mathfrak{p}\mid (P)}$ where $(p)=\mathfrak{p}\cap (p)$. Thus, we see that any prime dividing $A$ must lie above $2$ or $11$.

You are correct that $2R=(2,\sqrt{-6})^2$, and so evidently $f((2,\sqrt{-6})\mid (2))=1$. Similarly, $11 R=(11,\sqrt{-6}+4)(11,\sqrt{-6}+7)$ and so evidently $f(\mathfrak{q}\mid (11))=1$ for any prime $\mathfrak{q}$ dividing $11$.

Thus, we see that if $A$ is an ideal with $\|A\|=2^2\cdot 11^3$, then

$$A=(2,\sqrt{-6})^{e_1}(11,\sqrt{-6}+4)^{e_2}(11,\sqrt{-6}+7)^{e_3}$$

But, then

$$\begin{aligned}2^2\cdot 11^3 &=\|A\|\\ &=\|(2,\sqrt{-6})\|^{e_1}\|(11,\sqrt{-6}+4)\|^{e_1}\|(11,\sqrt{-6}+7)\|^{e_3}\\ &=2^{e_1}11^{e_2+e_3}\end{aligned}$$

So, $e_1=2$, and $e_1+e_2=3$ so that $(e_1,e_2)\in \{(3,0),(1,2),(2,1),(0,3)\}$. Thus, I count four ideals as well.